# How to get a list item on which another list item was dropped

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

Suppose I have two lists: a list of some products and a list of product categories. I would like to be able to move a product to a category by dropping it on a corresponding category list item. Here is the simple example:

```
<mat-list id="product-list" cdkDropList cdkDropListConnectedTo="category-list">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let product of products" cdkDrag>
      <span>product.name</span>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>

<mat-list id="category-list" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let category of categories">
      <span>category.name</span>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

For now `onDrop` handler is called but I don't know how to determine a category list item on which a product list item was dropped. Since category list items are not draggable `currentIndex` is always zero in event.

*Version of Angular/Angular Material is 12.1.3.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this issue with `elementFromPoint` function. Here is the updated example:

```
<mat-list id="product-list" cdkDropList>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let product of products" cdkDrag
                 (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnded($event, product)">
    <span>product.name</span>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>

<mat-list id="category-list">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let category of categories" class="drop-receiver"
                 (_drop)="onDrop($event, category)">
    <span>category.name</span>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

You can see that the lists are not connected anymore. Category list looks like an orginary one except its items have class `drop-receiver` and listener of custom `_drop` event.

In product list I listen `cdkDragEnded` event. Here is the code of the event handler:

```
onDragEnded(event: CdkDragEnd, product: Product) {
  const dropPointElement = document.elementFromPoint(event.dropPoint.x, event.dropPoint.y);
  if (dropPointElement) {
    const dropReceiver = dropPointElement.closest('.drop-receiver');
    if (dropReceiver) {
      const dropEvent = new CustomEvent('_drop', {detail: product});
      dropReceiver.dispatchEvent(dropEvent);
    }
  }
}
```

In example above I look for a DOM element using drop point coordinates. Then if element is found I look for a closest DOM element with class `drop-receiver`. Finally I send a custom event with name `_drop` to a drop receiver element. Now in handler of that event it it possible to implement some logic of assigning category to the selected product.